# How to use adapted learning rate in MxNet

Tags: mxnet

Learning rate is the key to the effect of my network.
When I define lr = 0.05, the train/validation-accuracy oscillate severely, however lr = 0.025 I cann't get any effect until Epoch[30].
So I remember the adapted learning rate in caffe, at first I choose a base lr = 0.1, as training going on, lr decays to 0.05, then 0.025 and smaller.
Does MxNet have this strategy, How can I use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of options to do that:

one is to use the **callback** function at the end of each batch/epoch:

```
sgd_opt = opt.SGD(learning_rate=0.005, momentum=0.9, wd=0.0001, rescale_grad=(1.0/batch_size))
model = mx.model.FeedForward(ctx=gpus, symbol=softmax, num_epoch=num_epoch,
              optimizer=sgd_opt, initializer=mx.init.Uniform(0.07))
def lr_callback(param):
    if param.nbatch % 10 == 0:
      sgd_opt.lr /= 10 # decrease learning rate by a factor of 10 every 10 batches
    print 'nbatch:%d, learning rate:%f' % (param.nbatch, sgd_opt.lr)

model.fit(X=train_dataiter, eval_data=test_dataiter, batch_end_callback=lr_callback)
```

The other is to use one of the [optimizers](https://github.com/dmlc/mxnet/blob/master/python/mxnet/optimizer.py) such as AdaGrad or ADAM

```
model = mx.model.FeedForward(
        ctx                = [mx.gpu(0)],
        num_epoch     = 60,
        symbol            = network,
        optimizer        =  'adam',
        initializer        = mx.init.Xavier(factor_type="in", magnitude=2.34))

model.fit(X= data_train)
```